# jgitflow-maven-plugin always produces merge conflict

Tags: jgitflow-maven-plugin

I have two branches: **master** and **develop**. At the starting point the **develop** branched from **master**

Now I try to make two releases in row:

1. First time I did "*mvn jgitflow:release-start*", "*mvn jgitflow:release-finish*". It has successfully create a release tag and causes no problem
2. Second time I did the same ("*mvn jgitflow:release-start*", "*mvn jgitflow:release-finish*"). This time I get a merge conflict error in my .pom files
3. Third time I made a merge commit from **develop** to **master**. After that I did "*mvn jgitflow:release-start*", "*mvn jgitflow:release-finish*". This time it has successfully done.

The problem is (2). I always get merge conflict error here if not doing (3)

Is there any way how to avoid manual merges (3) between **master** and **develop** branches to make a release with jgitflow-maven-plugin?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <flowInitContext>
        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
        <developBranchName>development</developBranchName>
        <featureBranchPrefix>feature-</featureBranchPrefix>
        <releaseBranchPrefix>release-</releaseBranchPrefix>
        <hotfixBranchPrefix>hotfix-</hotfixBranchPrefix>
        <versionTagPrefix>version-</versionTagPrefix>
      </flowInitContext>
      <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
      <squash>true</squash>
      <scmCommentPrefix>[RELEASE] </scmCommentPrefix>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```